# Is there a way to store the output of a linux command into a variable in python network programming?

Tags: linux, network-programming, python-3.7

I am trying to build a system where a list of the available wifi networks would be stored for some specific purpose. Now the problem is that executing a system command with os.system() in a variable 'res' only stores the return value of the command which is useless to me at this point.

I know of no approach that provide me the desired result.

```
import os
res = os.system('nmcli dev wifi')
```

The variable res must store all the desired result into it rather than the return value. Even if it stores result, it will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the Popen method from the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


#First argument is the program name.
arguments = ['ls', '-l', '-a']

#Run the program ls as subprocess.
process = Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

#Get the output or any errors. Be aware, they are going to be
#in bytes!!!
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

#Print the output of the ls command.
print(bytes.decode(stdout))
```

Comment: Also check out the [Byte objects vs String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/byte-objects-vs-string-python/) if you don't know what the ```bytes.decode()``` does.